# Dynamically set Unicorn listen address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I've about 10 nodes running Unicorn. I'd like to lock down the listen address to eth1 on each node.

I'm setting an environment variable

```
export ETH1=`/sbin/ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`
```

then trying to load in config/unicorn.rb

```
ipaddress = ENV["ETH1"]
listen "#{ipaddress}:8080", :tcp_nopush => true
```

Unicorn starts but is still listening on all interfaces. At any time there can be less or more than 10 nodes which is why I want to do this dynamically.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `grep listen config/unicorn.rb` returns the only one line?

Comment: @mudasobwa - I've also `listen "#{shared}/sockets/unicorn.sock", backlog: 64`